# Extra space in HTML email shown in Outlook email cient

Tags: html, html-email, email-client

I created a html email and it looks great in all browser clients like hotmail and gmail. Also works great in Entourage. The only place it will not work great in is Outlook.

Here is a screenshot to of the email from both outlook and other email clients:
http://www.theadamgrp.com/client-demos/vanguard/email-screenshot.png

Here is the link to my code:
http://www.theadamgrp.com/client-demos/vanguard/email-04.html

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this style to your  cell

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```